# Using AppleScript to copy a webpage TITLE to clipboard

Tags: applescript

I am looking to copy the webpage title (of an open webpage in safari) to the clipboard using apple script (or a javascript snippet will do).

I will then use that Variable in Automator.

I have looked all over the web, but cannot seem to find the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried this with Safari and it seems to work as expected:

```
tell application "Safari"
    get name of document 1
end tell
```